# Route traffic from one port to another machine in LAN

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, firewall, hamachi

I would like to remote desktop to my work computer using hamachi. The hamachi connection works fine and i can use remote desktop but when my session is over hamachi disconects.

I was thinking i could set up another computer (a virtual machine) with windows xp and send request to that machine, the virtual machine redirects the traffic to lan at work and then i can connect to work computer.

Basicly i would like to forward the traffic from the hamachi adapter to LAN Adapter in the virtual machine witch is connected to a bridge adapter to the HOST machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds possible, but if you're doing all this, then I'd eliminate hamachi and just use Windows Remote Desktop.  Google port forwarding for Windows.

Comment: you lose me more with each paragraph.  Hamache is like logmein, web, or is it app?  How is having a virtual machine as proxy in between, going to stop the problem that when your session is over, hamachi disconnects? why is your session becoming over? is it because you are disconnecting hamachi?  If you can send a "request" (try to connect via hamachi) to your virtual machine, and it keeps the connection, then why can't you send it to your work computer? then you talk of "the hamachi adapter". since when was hamachi an adapter!!

Comment: It's an experiment. Hamachi is from logmein. The software creates a virtual lan adapter. Hamachi make some changes and it stop running as a service. It only works when the user is logged in. Using remote desktop, when the session is over hamachi disconnects and becomes unreachable.